# How to hide UpDown buttons in Inactive cells for DataGridView NumericUpDownColumn

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, numericupdown

Thanks in advance...

I am a VB coder with limited C# experience. I am trying to implement the MSDN C# solution for adding a NumericUpDown column to a DataGridView from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa730881(v=vs.80)). It works fine except that the UpDown buttons are visible on all of the DataGrid cells, not just the one being edited.

I also have a VB solution that hides the UpDown buttons for inactive cells, but doesn't have Minimum/Maximum values. I have tried to apply the C# Minimum/Maximum properties into the VB version, but my C# is not good enough.

Is there a way to direct the DataGridViewNumericUpDownEditingControl or DataGridViewNumericUpDownCell to only show the NumericUpDown control when the focus is moved to the cell.

This is how I use the column:

```
Protected Sub AddUpDownColumn(ByVal colNo As Integer, ByVal minValue As Integer, byval maxValue As Integer)
    ' The UpDown column replaces a std column at position colNo

    Dim udCol As New DataGridViewUpDownColumn

    ' Use the original Header & width
    udCol.HeaderText = DataView.Columns(colNo).HeaderText
    udCol.Width = DataView.Columns(colNo).Width

    udCol.Visible = True
    udCol.Minimum = minValue
    udCol.Maximum = maxValue

    ' This is the table column
    udCol.DataPropertyName = SourceData.FieldName(colNo)

    'Remove the original column and replace it with the UpDown column
    DataView.Columns.RemoveAt(colNo)
    DataView.Columns.Insert(colNo, udCol)

End Sub
```

Thankyou

Comment: Remove Paint method from DataGridViewNumericUpDownCell

Comment: This is how I use the column:

Comment: The [following](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/datagridview-numeric-column) has a custom numeric column with no spinners. Column code is C#, implemented in vb.net. See readme.md for original author on Code Project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions.
I have found a neat solution.
In the derived Cell's Paint routine I have added a line at the end of the block preceded by the comment // Set all the relevant properties

```
                paintingNumericUpDown.Controls[0].Visible = false;
```

Controls[0] is the updown part. Controls[1] is the textbox. This works well.